# Can I make one row show at a time in a table?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript function that toggles the display for rows in a table.  The dilemma is that I would like to display one row at a time.  What is a neat way to do this?

```
    function optionSelected() {
        var optionSelect = document.getElementById('ddlSelect');
        var strTest = optionSelect.options[optionSelect.selectedIndex].value;            
        var rowHeader = document.getElementById(strTest);
        var row = document.getElementById(strTest);

        if (rowHeader.style.display == '') {
            rowHeader.style.display = 'none';
            row.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            rowHeader.style.display = '';
            row.style.display = '';
        }
    }  


<select id="ddlSelect" onchange="optionSelected()">
    <option value="optionA">A</option>
    <option value="optionB">B</option>
    <option value="optionC">C</option>
    <option value="optionD">D</option>
</select>

<table id="tableList">
    <tr id="optionA"><td>DisplayA</td></tr>
    <tr id="optionB"><td>DisplayB</td></tr>
    <tr id="optionC"><td>DisplayC</td></tr>
    <tr id="optionD"><td>DisplayD</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can we see the markup for your table, and the 'ddlSelect' field?

Comment: @belugabob - Sorry I was lost in my lookup.

Comment: Can you clarify your question. What you've posted seems to do what you need: shows one row at a time, according to the user's selection

Comment: You have a typo in your example. That is "=" sign right after "<select".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple with jquery

```
$('tr').hide();
$('#'+strTest).show();
```

Comment: The first statement hides any and all table rows in the document. The second will show a specific row identified by the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is your vanilla Javascript solution (although I'd rather go with jQuery):

```
function optionSelected() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('ddlSelect');

    for (var i=0; i<sel.options.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(sel.options[i].value)
            .style.display = sel.options[i].selected ? '' : 'none';
    }
}​
```

Also, if you want to initialize your display, you should call `optionSelected()` once in an onLoad handler.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping on DOM nodes, you can change style rules and use the speed of the CSS selectors instead.

Here is an example to show one line at a time and stay.
If you want to remove them at each selection you can clear the style each time you make a selection.

```
<body>
    <style id="styles">
        table tr{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <select id="ddlSelect" onchange="optionSelected()">
        <option value="optionA">A</option>
        <option value="optionB">B</option>
        <option value="optionC">C</option>
        <option value="optionD">D</option>
    </select>

    <table>
        <tr id="optionA"><td>DisplayA</td></tr>
        <tr id="optionB"><td>DisplayB</td></tr>
        <tr id="optionC"><td>DisplayC</td></tr>
        <tr id="optionD"><td>DisplayD</td></tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        function optionSelected() {
            var optionSelect = document.getElementById('ddlSelect'),
                    styles = document.getElementById('styles'),
                    selector = '#' + optionSelect.options[optionSelect.selectedIndex].value,
                    rule = 'display:block';
                    if(styles.styleSheet){
                        styles.styleSheet.cssText = selector + '{' + rule + '}';
                    }else{
                        styles.appendChild(document.createTextNode(selector + '{' + rule + '}'));
                    }
        }  
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Interesting dynamic manipulation of the stylesheet - Not sure I'd do it that way myself as the effects could potentially be too global. I'd prefer to apply hide/show operation to the specific elements to be shown or hidden. All a matter of taste,I suppose.